# Rails routing, removing controller extension

Tags: ruby-on-rails

current routes:

```
  devise_for :users
  root 'front#index'
  get 'front/index'
  get 'front/api'
  get 'front/howitworks'
  get 'front/getstarted'
  get 'front/blog'
  get 'front/support'
```

so at the moment its www.url.co.uk/front/index and www.url.co.uk/front/howitworks

I want it to be www.url.co.uk/ and www.url.co.uk/howitworks

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So, if you do `root 'front#index'` - www.url.co.uk/ should lead you to `index` action of your `front_controller`.

If you do `get '/howitworks' => 'front#howitworks'` - then www.url.co.uk/howitworks will work to.

Comment: Thanks Phil, however, this does not update the front_howitworks_path route:( as its still /front/howitworks for that path.

Comment: to update the path, you should do get '/howitworks' => 'front#howitworks', as: "front_howitworks"

Comment: and remove the get 'front/howitworks' path in the beginning of ht file :P